# To form Html Href in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<a href="BasicInfo.aspx" class="desc3 pull-right"><i class="icon-edit">
```

I have a simple html href in mvc.
now i require to manipulate the path as we use to do in asp.net suppose we have a url like this

```
http://localhost:52086/VisaCase/?Summary=317
```

Now i require to take the value of summary, as we do in asp.net using `Request.querystring`
and want to form the full Href Url

like

Note: i want to do this in the View of the MVC. Thanks for an assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Request.Params["Summary"]
```

This should give you the value of `Summary` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct but you should collect them in the controller or contemplate in routing template. The last one will avoid you to include because will be get from request.